# Расположение графики вместе с заголовком в Latex

Tags: latex

У меня есть мысль, чтобы страница latex генерировалась располагалась таким образом:

```
заголовок заголовок заголовок заголовок
текст текст текст   картинка картинка
текст текст текст   картинка картинка
текст текст текст   картинка картинка
текст текст текст   картинка картинка
```

я использовал окружение wrapfigure, заголовок генерируется в столбце слева,
добавление заголовка внутрь окружения, увы тоже не помогло

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите минимальный пример с кодом, тогда можно будет его подправить и предложить решение проблемы. Если на словах, то можно, например, воспользоваться командой `\parbox` (или окружением `minipage`), и сделать в таких блоках текст и рядом картину. А заголовок расположить до них *вне* окружений.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/248924/vladimir, иначе я бы забыл про этот вопрос.

Я нашел ответ

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \subsection{Заголовок}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.50\linewidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics{initRawPart}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.50\linewidth}
        \vspace{0pt}\raggedright
        подписи к рисунку
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{initRawPart}
\end{figure}
```

Важные моменты:

- Окружением figure сложно управлять, поэтому, чтобы загаловок был точно над кортинкой, надо поместить его в figure
- Если просто разделить страницу на 2 minipages, то мы обнаружим, что текст во
  второй mp начинает генерироваться с центра; для решения данной проблемы добавляем нулевой пробел в начале каждого mp. Этот материал был взят с (https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1059), однако там человек ссылается на некорректный адрес, поэтому причин данного явления рассказать не могу.